# How to validate that a Gitlab CI job has not modified tracked files

Tags: git, gitlab-ci

I would like to add a Gitlab job:

Check if the generated files are different than the ones committed in git.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git diff --exit-code` after running the generation script to assert whether files have changed.

For example, suppose you modify an existing file then run `git diff --exit-code`, the command will exit non-zero. In a gitlab job, that means the job will fail.

```bash
$ echo "foo" >> existing-file.txt
$ git diff --exit-code # exits non-zero (failure)
```

So, you could have a gitlab job that runs your generation script then checks if the files have changed. If the files don't change, the command exits 0 and the job passes.

```yaml
check_openapi:
  stage: .pre
  # ...
  script:
    - ./mvnw verify  # generate the openapi docs
    - git diff --exit-code  # fails if the files tracked by git have changed
```

It's important to note that `git diff` will only work on tracked git files. Therefore, if your generation code potentially adds *new* files, you should make sure that you run `git add --intent-to-add` for any *newly* created files. Otherwise, you may miss some cases because new files aren't tracked by git by default. You can add this to the CI job or you can incorporate it into your code generation script.

In example:

```bash
$ echo "foo" > newfile.txt
$ git diff --exit-code  # exits 0 (success?!)
```

```bash
$ echo "foo" > newfile.txt
$ git add --intent-to-add ./newfile.txt
$ git diff --exit-code # exits non-zero (failure)
```

So, if your generation script doesn't run `git add --intent-to-add` as part of its process, a complete solution may look like this:

```yaml
check_openapi:
  stage: .pre
  # ...
  script:
    - ./mvnw verify
    - git add --intent-to-add .  # make sure new files are tracked/diff'd
    - git diff --exit-code
```